# Selecting specific text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Suppose I have the string in the variable below:

```
text='lsdkjfkj fksjf aksjdafhIncident 11202asdf jfsaldfuaeia'
```

I'd like to select only the text `Incident 11202` and save it to a variable.

Also, the numbers that follow 'Incident' will change.

I'd like to know if there is a way to copy any unknown characters that followed it.

Comment: regex sounds like it would be useful here

Comment: Do you specifically mean that you want to find the word "Incident " followed by a series of numbers? or are there some other criteria you're looking for?

Comment: Take a look at the re module, regular expressions are documented there. https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Generally, on Stack Overflow, you show the code you've tried.  That way we have an idea of what you know, and what you need.  We don't typically only spoon feed you information.  In this specific case, can you define exactly what you want?  If you can, you might even be able to solve this yourself.  Will your string always have "Incident" in it, and you want to extract "Incident" and whatever number is in the following word?

Comment: You are receiving downvotes because the question is not (yet) a good one - lacking in details, like khelwood and I mentioned.  Please read [ask], and edit your question.  (It's almost certain to be put on hold while you do so, but just rewrite your question with useful information, and you'll get a positive response.)

Comment: Do you know how many digits you are matching? Is it always the same number of digits?

Comment: @Steampunkery `I didn't know the numbers that followed 'Incident'`

Comment: Ok, I'll write you a regex and post it in a sec

Comment: @Scott Mermelstein My apologizes for not providing enough details. I honestly did not have any idea on how to proceed with what I wanted - and as a result, had no code to provide. I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: @khelwood Yes, a series of numbers.

Comment: Apologizing to me isn't necessary.  You got answers that are hopefully helpful to you - and were lucky enough to have some knowledgeable people willing to guess at what you want.  One of the goals of Stack Overflow is to make a good repository of questions, and the goal is to think that the questions and answers aren't specifically for you, but for the next 100 people coming by with your question in mind.  So the better you make your question, the happier the community at large is in trying to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex for that.

Try the following regex for example:

```
import re
txt='lsdkjfkj fksjf aksjdafhIncident 11202asdf jfsaldfuaei2a'
print (re.findall ('Incident.\d*', txt))

>>>['Incident 11202']
```

**What is regex?**

A regular expression (regex or regexp for short) is a special text string for describing a search pattern

**What is findAll function?**

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return all non-overlapping
> matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is
> scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If
> one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
> groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
> group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the
> beginning of another match.

You can read more in [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works! 2 Questions - 1.) How does this regex code know to stop at 5 digits. 2.) Can I specify to record any number of characters following a 'Incident'? - like "copy any characters within 6 spaces following the string 'Incident'.

Comment: It does not.. The regex stop when the numbers are ended with a character who is not a number. Is that what you need or do you need specific five numbers? Kindly ask to accept the answer if it resolved your issue.

Comment: The code does what I need it to do - I was just curious. Thanks and I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, you need regexes. Here's the code you need, with an explanation below it:

```
import re

the_regex = re.compile(r'(Incident\s+\d+)')
string_to_search_in = 'lsdkjfkj fksjf aksjdafhIncident 11202asdf jfsaldfuaei2a'
matches = re.findall(the_regex, string_to_search_in)
print(matches)

Output: ['Incident 11202']
```

Here's a step by step of the code:

- Line 1: Imports the re module (short for regex)
- Line 2: assigns the regex to the `the_regex` variable. The regex I wrote will match anything starting with "Incident", then any amount of consecutive white space (spaces, tabs, etc) then any amount of consecutive digits. The `re.compile` part of that line compiles the regex for more efficient use
- Line 3: Assigns the string we want the regex to search in
- Line 4: Does the actual match. `re.findall` will (not surprisingly) find **all** of the matches to the regex and return them as strings in a list
- Line 5: Prints the output of it all (see above for output)

**Regexes**

Are a useful tool to help you find sequences of characters in a string or file. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is the python 3.6.1 documentation for re. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is the Wikipedia page on regexes.